# How To find Exact string match within a String in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have an oracle table that has a column called system_access that has the following data:

```
Read Only, Write, read only, Admin
Read, Write, read only, Admin
Admin, Read Only (no), read only(see mgr), Admin
```

Based on the above sample data, I am unsure of my query to only retrieve records that match the exact words of "Read Only" and/or "read only"

I do not need the records that have the "Read Only (no)" with space then bracket after it or before it or "read only(see mgr)" with no space and bracket after it or before it.

So based on above sample data, I would only get back two rows only, i.e.:

```
Read Only, Write, read only, Admin
Read, Write, read only, Admin
```

As mentioned, only records that match exactly the string "Read Only" or "read only"

Comment: This definitely looks like a conception error to me. You are breaking the first normal form ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form ) and this is completely non evolutive. I highly suggest you to modify your current design if possible.

Comment: @Vincent Savard, totally agree with you but unfortunately inherited this design error and at this point there is no scope of correcting the design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes it's useful to add something to the string before you compare it, then every element follows the same format:

```
with testData as
(
  select 'Read Only, Write, read only, Admin' test from dual union all
  select 'Read, Write, read only, Admin'  test from dual union all
  select 'Admin, Read Only (no), read only(see mgr), Admin' test from dual
)
select * from testData
where lower(test)||',' like '%read only,%';
```

Answer (score 1):

to take @Bob Jarvis (although I couldn
t get his to work with the data sample below) one step farther and drop the OR

```
WITH DATA AS(
SELECT '1- Read Only, Write, read only, Admin' SYSTEM_ACCESS FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '2- Write, Admin,Read Only' SYSTEM_ACCESS FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '3- Read, Write, read only, Admin' SYSTEM_ACCESS FROM DUAL UNION
select '4- ADMIN, READ ONLY (NO), READ ONLY(SEE MGR), ADMIN' system_access from dual 
)
select * 
  FROM DATA
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(SYSTEM_ACCESS, '(read only[ ,]+[^/(])|(read only$)','i');
```

**REGEXP_LIKE(SYSTEM_ACCESS, '(read only[ ,]+[^/(])|(read only$)','i');**
this will look for all instances of "read only" that may have a space or comma after it but prohibits the opening (, or the 'read only' at the end of the string.

(http://www.regular-expressions.info/oracle.html & http://psoug.org/snippet.htm/Regular_Expressions_Regex_Cheat_Sheet_856.htm?PHPSESSID=7238be874ab99d0731a9da64f2dbafd8)

Comment: I think you're right, the two regexp's can be combined with a "|" between them.  As I said, I'm far from a regular expression guru...  :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis, nor am I!  I try to find reasons to use it each day just to get more fluent with it, it's one of those things that I am really starting to love in find and replace

Answer (score 0):

select * from table
where lower(trim(column_name)) = 'read only'

Comment: I think you have missed that there is not only one piece of data in this column but multiple "Read Only, Write, read only, Admin"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE
  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(system_access, '[^()]. read only. [^()],', 'i') OR
        REGEXP_LIKE(system_access, '[^()]. read only. [^()]$', 'i');
```

I think this will work for the data shown but it's late, I'm far from a regular expression guru, and I don't have docs handy.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where lower(system_access) like '%read only,%';
```

This will work as long as the table data doesn't change.  Using REGEX will work as well but the regex would have to be crafted correctly and again, if the data changes it all is for naught.

Comment: This won't work if the "read only" happens to be at the end of the list.

Comment: ...although it will if `lower(system_access)` is changed to `lower(system_access) || ','`.

Comment: Yes, but the full table content was included in the question, this is why I clarified my answer with 'as long as the table data doesn't change'

Answer (score 0):

The searching `"%read only,%"` method in [@jonearles answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102825/how-to-find-exact-string-match-within-a-string-in-oracle/4103253#4103253) will work fine. However, because of the clearly mad underlying design you've been lumbered with, it might be appropriate to add a bit of rigour to the permissions test.

I'd be tempted to assume you always have a comma-delimited string and when doing a permissions test parse the text and check for the specific entries "Read Only" and "read only".

You might also look to extend this by checking each token in the parsed permission string against a table containing the known set of roles, i.e. "Read Only", "read only(see mgr)". This table could even contain a flag that matched *your* definition of 'Read-Only' that you could use in your query.